# Is logistic regression beta-coefficient estimates unbiased, consistent asymptotically efficient, normal?

Tags: statistics, variance, parameter-estimation, estimation

Seeing how in social sciences the Cramér-Rao lower bound is used as variances of the found parameters it would seem that the parameters are both unbiased and efficient, but what is the proof for this? Is there a specific paper or book I could read this in and refer to?

Comment: Correct spelling is Cramér. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%E2%80%93Rao_bound#Single-parameter_proof

Comment: Inlogistic regression you use a maximum likelihood estimation (MLE) to estimate your coefficients. In this link http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood, in the "Properties" section you can find more details regarding unbiasedness and efficientcy